# Debug Java program by executing "gradle run"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gradle

I have a Gradle project in Eclipse IDE and I usually use the option `gradle run` to run my Java application.

I have an error in my Java code and I want to debug it, but when I execute `gradle run`, the debugger doesn't stop in the breakpoints. In the "Debug as" menu, I don't have anything like `gradle debug`.

How can I debug my application?

Comment: Have you tried `gradle run --debug-jvm` ?

Comment: I will try it, but I wanted to debug using the eclipse IDE

Comment: There is a discussion on https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-attach-a-debugger-to-gradle-so-that-i-can-debug-it-running-a-task/7526 on how to debug in eclipse using gradle tasks.

Answer (score 56):

Even though the accepted answer should work, you can achieve it in a much easier way.

---

1. Just run `gradle run --debug-jvm`. This starts the application in remote debug mode, and you can attach with any remote debugger, e.g., Eclipse, on port `5005`.
2. Assuming you use Eclipse as IDE: In Eclipse, go on your Project -> Debug as... -> Debug Configuration -> Remote Java Application. As host set `localhost`, as port `5005`, and you are free to go.

---

For more information [see the official Gradle Java plugin doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test) regarding testing.

> [...] can also be enabled at invocation time via the --debug-jvm task option (since Gradle 1.12).

Comment: this works, but not the accepted answer. The gradle one is the one actually works.

Comment: this works indeed. to change the default port, in the build.gradle file test section add like this: test {
jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5099"]
}

Comment: Is there a commandline switch to make this suspend when Eclipse connects, which doesn't require changing `jvmArgs` in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Here is the Gradle official guide. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:debugging_java_tests

Comment: Some IDE-s use a debug task.  Which could work before Gradle 7 if you add some code tweaks to the task.  Instead replace the IDE `debug` operation `project:debug` with something like: `project:run --debug-jvm`.  Then the IDE works correctly.  Oh and similarly for debugging a test.

Comment: If you have gradle in your project as a wrapper (and you likely don't have gradle installed by itself on your system) and you're using Eclipse:
1) Locate the `gradlew` file in your project
2) Open up a new terminal in Eclipse by going into the package explorer and right clicking the project containing `gradlew` > Show in Local Terminal > Terminal
3) Within the newly created terminal, enter `gradlew run --debug-jvm`
4) Perform step 2 in the answer above.

Answer (score 33):

To debug a Gradle project in Eclipse follow these steps:

**Step 1**:
Put these in the `build.gradle` file:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9099'
    }
}
```

**Step 2**:

From the root of your project run:

```
gradle -DDEBUG=true run
```

You will now see something like this in the console:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9099
```

**Step 3**:

Now set breakpoints in Eclipse in your source files.

**Step 4**:

As last step, now right-click in Eclipse on Project > Debug as > Debug configuration > Remote Java application.

There you have to set these fields:

```
1. Project (this should be set to name of your Eclipse project)
2. Host (here it's localhost)
3. Port (in this example it will be 9099)
```

Click "Debug". Now your program will stop whenever it hits a breakpoint in Eclipse.

To see details of these steps with an example project see [this gradle example on GitHub](https://github.com/ayonious/gradle-tutorial/tree/master/remote-debugging1):

Comment: Hey, when I try your steps, setting the debug configuration for remote application results in the error message Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
I am trying to run a task that executes my cucumber tests from gradle, and stop at a breakpoint in the Java code. Any tips?

Comment: Hey @themathmagician, Im havent used cucumber tests but if its some kind of unit test you need to change the gradle function a little.Follow this example for unit tests: https://github.com/ayonious/gradle-tutorial/tree/master/remote-debugging2

Comment: This worked for me but I needed to change `debug_socket` to `dt_socket`. `jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9099'`

Comment: @Jerinaw thanks for mentioning it updating my answer

Comment: Xrunjdwp is for Java 1.4 or less

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to run the gradle task in debug mode through adding the following code in build.gradle file.

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005'
    }
}
```

Instead I did the following steps and managed to run it automatically in debug mode :

1. All you need to to do is to go to $GRADLE_HOME/bin.
2. Edit the file gradle or gradle.bat depending on your OS.
3. Set the JVM parameter in the OS-specific way. For example:

gradle(UNIX) case :

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xdebug-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

gradle.bat(NT) case :

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

.
 4. Run the Gradle command from the console.